# PHP file with index.html (visual studio)

Tags: php, html, css, visual-studio

I am trying to run `npm start` on my whole project that includes a index.html, index.css however I am having difficulties.

Everything was normal until I introduced PHP into my index.html file because I am trying to create a real time chat application that runs on my localhost.

For some reason my PHP code which is in my index.html is white and is not being recognised as code. Some parts of the code when ran as normal shows as text even though it is PHP functions.

So I tried changing the extension to .php and it now recognises the code. However, I now can not run `npm start` because index.html is not found.

I really want to run my html file with the php code inside of it although keeping it as a .html extension. Is there any way to do that? Or anyway to solve this?

```
<div class="col-sm-4">
            <br>
            <br>
              <div id="wrapper">
                <div id="menu">
                    <h4 class="welcome"><strong>Live Chat </strong><b></b></h4>
                </div>
     
                <div id="chatbox"></div>
     
                <form name="message" action="">
                    <input name="usermsg" type="text" id="usermsg" />
                    <input name="submitmsg" type="submit" id="submitmsg" value="Send" />
                </form>
            </div>
            <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
            <script type="text/javascript">
                // jQuery Document
                $(document).ready(function () {});
            </script>
            
            <?php
            session_start();
            
            if(isset($_POST['enter'])){
              if($_POST['name'] != ""){
                $_SESSION['name'] = stripslashes(htmlspecialchars($_POST['name']));
              }
              else{
                echo '<span class="error">Please type in a name</span>';
              }
            }
            
            function loginForm(){
              echo'
              <div id="loginform">
                <p>Please enter your name to continue!</p>
                <form action="index.php" method="post">
                  <label for="name">Name &mdash;</label>
                  <input type="text" name="name" id="name" />
                  <input type="submit" name="enter" id="enter" value="Enter" />
                </form>
              </div>
              ';
            }
            ?>
            </div>
```

This is the code that is not being recognised as PHP inside my html file. Not really all of it, but most of it. This part specifically.

```
<?php
            session_start();
            
            if(isset($_POST['enter'])){
              if($_POST['name'] != ""){
                $_SESSION['name'] = stripslashes(htmlspecialchars($_POST['name']));
              }
              else{
                echo '<span class="error">Please type in a name</span>';
              }
            }
            
            function loginForm(){
              echo'
              <div id="loginform">
                <p>Please enter your name to continue!</p>
```

Comment: PHP will be parsed only in `.php` files, unless you tell your server otherwise

Comment: How do I tell my server?

I am using visual studio and want to run ```npm start``` whilst still having the index.html with php code inside of it.

Comment: @brombeer as in, how do I make it recognise it as PHP and actually work it out?

Comment: Which server are you using?

Comment: Sorry I do not know how to respond to that as I am new, but I assume, localhost:3000? That is what happens when I run npm start.

Comment: Err, ok, so `npm start` runs a webserver it seems. Sorry, no clue. Have you made sure that this server can run/execute php code?

Comment: @brombeer I do not know how to make sure the server can run/execute php code.

Comment: Doesn't npm start run a nodejs server? If you want to run PHP, you need a server with PHP support. If you're running nodejs, then just use nodejs for it. It's probably even better for a live chat than PHP. If you're not using nodejs on your site, then build the PHP parts as an API (on a different web server with a different port) and use JS to connect to it.